# Can I unplug a failing dynamic disk and plug it into another computer?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, dynamic-disk

I just wondered if it is possible to unplug a dynamic disk (hard drive) and plug it into another computer?

The reason I ask is that one of my HDDs with Windows on it is about to fail, and I don't want to install Windows on another HDD and find that I can't access the data on the other dynamic disks because of some sort of technique that I missed.

Comment: You should plug in a new drive, clone the failing drive, then replace it with the new drive.  Installing it on another computer at this point is just asking for problems, hopeful you already have a recent backup, incase this procedure fails.

Comment: Don't know if this matters, but it likely won't boot in another computer so either boot to a Live CD and copy the files from that or do as Ramhound suggests and clone the drive ASAP.

Comment: sorry guys, but that wasnt the question.
Since the system had failed and the other disks in the system were dynamic, I wanted to know if I can take the good dynamic disks can connect them to another computer or new install. These good disks are not hosting OS'es, just data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer was "Yes", they just need to be turned online from the disk manager, and any software raid partitions will be marked as faulty unless both dynamic disks were reconnected to the new system